# Getting a radiogroup to extend evenly horizontally with match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get it to match_parent properly. What I want it to do is to extend to the end of the page like the image below. 
I've tried practically everything, but the only solution I've come up with is adding a fixed px, which is something I do not want to do because it conflicts across different platforms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="net.battleplugins.msutton.fragemento.MainActivity">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_row">

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation='horizontal'>

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/quiz_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/quiz_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/picture_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/picture_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>


                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/events_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/events_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'm getting is this:

[image: Image of the emulation where it doesn't extend like match_parent is intended]

What I want it to do is this:

[image: Image of the emulation correctly spaced but with fixed width]

The problem with this is that this is a fixed amount. 
android:layout_width="1075px" in the RadioGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use LinearLayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="net.battleplugins.msutton.fragemento.MainActivity">
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation='horizontal'>

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/quiz_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/quiz_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/picture_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/picture_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>


                <RadioButton
                    android:text="@string/events_button_title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/events_button"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="updateFragment"/>
            </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might be a god. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Using weight, instead of set absoluted width.

```
    <RadioGroup
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation='horizontal'>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout is best Approach to achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="net.battleplugins.msutton.fragemento.MainActivity">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation='horizontal'>

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/quiz_button_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/quiz_button"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="updateFragment"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/picture_button_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/picture_button"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="updateFragment"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:text="@string/events_button_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/events_button"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="updateFragment"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `TableLayout`, specify `android:stretchColumns="1"` in your `TableLayout` and `android:layout_column="1"` in your `RadioGroup`.